# problem in citing an online link

Tags: bibliographies

I have an online material to cite as following:

```
@misc{liushort,
    author = "{Liu, Qiang}",
    title = {{A Short Introduction to Kernelized Stein Discrepancy}},
    howpublished = "[Online]. Available from: \url{https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lqiang/PDF/ksd_short.pdf}",
    note = {Online; accessed 18 March 2021} ,
    year=2016,
}
```

But, the link is not shown properly. I believe the error is in characters "~" and "_". How can i solve this issue.

Comment: That should work if you load `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}`. But note that if you indeed use `biblatex` as your tag suggests, there are much better ways to write `@online` entries than this. (You'd use the type `@online` and could use the dedicated `url` and `urldate` fields for URL and access date instead of `howpublished` and `note`.) Please show us a minimal, yet compilable example document that tells us how you cite this entry in your document and what your bibliography setup looks like.

Comment: If I use @online, url and urldate, the hyperlink is not shown in the reference. Only title and author are shown

Comment: using \usepackage{hyperref}, works well

Comment: Hi, since you are evidently new here: the key point that @moewe is trying to make is that there are two bibliography systems for LaTeX, called `bibtex` and `biblatex` respectively. The two have different features, and answers valid for one may not be valid for the other. If you are using `bibtex` to prepare the bibliography, you should change the tag on the question so you are not suggesting that you are using `biblatex`.

Comment: If `\usepackage{hyperref}` helped you did not in fact use `biblatex`, so I removed the tag.